# When particle mo is used to mean also, particle wa is omitted. Does mo also replace ga?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が, particle-も

The question is clear but I would like to add an example. (My sentence may have other errors as well)

> I am glad that you think the same.
> あなた**が**そう思いますうれしいです
>
> I am glad that you think the same, too.
> あなた**も**そう思いますうれしいです

Is this conversion correct?

Comment: Your conversion of が to も is fine, but "思いますうれしいです" isn't. You'll need to change the ending of 思います to て form for this to make sense, considering that you being 嬉{うれ}しい is a result of あなたもそう思います

Comment: Is it supposed to be two sentences?

Comment: "I am glad that you think so" = あなたがそう思って くれて うれしい

Answer (score 0, accepted):

も　replaces が in the sense that it does not become がも like you have でも　or にも。

> 「 あれ見て。猫がいるよ。」「どこに？あ、いたね。」「（興奮）あ、あ、あ、子猫も！かわいい〜」

It's really hard to make examples.  But here 子猫も　the も　replaces 子猫がいる